# SQL Server 2016, Is this the best way to clear logs?

Tags: sql-server

I to insert about 2 billions rows in a table as part of an upgrade. The logs keep getting full so I need to clear it. The recovery model is simple but I am also interested in Full recovery model solutions where I don't have to keep performing backups in prod.

How do I keep the transaction logs to a minimum while inserting so many rows?

Currently I have a loop, something like:

```
loop for 2 billion records
CHECKPOINT;
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   INSERT INTO *** SELECT * FROM xxx
END TRANSACTION
CHECKPOINT;
```

What does this do? I am trying to understand the code below. Will this clear logs? Are these system SPs or has someone written these SPs?

```
-- Check the integrity of the databases (Truncates any logs)
EXECUTE master.dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck
@Databases = 'myDB',
@CheckCommands = 'CHECKDB',
@LogToTable = 'Y'-- Update index statistics

GO

--reindex
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
    @Databases = 'myDB',
    @FragmentationLow = NULL,
    @FragmentationMedium = NULL,
    @FragmentationHigh = NULL,
    @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
    @LogToTable = 'Y'
GO
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with your logs? Seems like you would do MUCH better to talk about that.

Comment: You need [minimal logging](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1185/minimally-logging-bulk-load-inserts-into-sql-server/) See also [Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/minimal-logging-fast-load-context) Give or take, you need to do a *single* insert for the whole thing and add `TABLOCK`, although it is possible to get minimal logging without that under some circumstances

Comment: Regarding the maintenance procs, see https://ola.hallengren.com/.

Comment: How big is your **Transaction Log** file and the drive that supports it? What are your intentions with the table after it has the 2 billion rows in it? Generally it's advised against to clear (shrink) the **Transaction Log** because it's a heavy operation that is mostly pointless when it's likely going to re-grow anyway. When the drive that the log file is on is full, that doesn't necessarily mean the log file itself is full, SQL Server has an internal mechanism to maintain the log file and re-use the space it's consuming from the disk. A 2 billion row table likely should have a big log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The recovery model is simple...

> How do I keep the transaction logs to a minimum while inserting so many rows?

In the simple recovery model, you can clear the transaction log (and prevent it from continuously growing) by batching your billion rows into multiple transactions, and issuing `CHECKPOINT`s periodically.  The overall flow is like this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentId AS int = 0;

WHILE @CurrentId < (SELECT MAX(ot.Id) FROM dbo.OldTable ot)
BEGIN;

    INSERT INTO dbo.NewTable
    SELECT TOP (1000000) ot.ID
    FROM dbo.OldTable ot
    WHERE ot.Id > @CurrentId
    ORDER BY ot.Id;

    CHECKPOINT;
    SET @CurrentId = (SELECT MAX(nt.Id) FROM dbo.NewTable nt);
END;
```

This inserts a million rows at a time from `OldTable` into `NewTable`. Notice I'm using `@CurrentId` to keep track of that, and issuing a `CHECKPOINT` after each insert (to make sure the log can clear).  You'll need to use some mechanism like that to batch your inserts and keep track of what still needs to be inserted.

Also notice that this isn't all in one big transaction.  That would also prevent the log from clearing.

> Will this clear logs? Are these system SPs or has someone written these SPs?

No, neither of those procs will clear the logs.  They aren't system stored procedures, they are part of [Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).  `dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck` runs `DBCC CHECKDB`, and `dbo.IndexOptimize` rebuilds or reorganizes indexes.  Both of those things are unrelated to the transaction log.

> I am also interested in Full recovery model solutions where I don't have to keep performing backups in prod

Performing log backups is the only way to keep the transaction log from growing in the full recovery model.  You'll have to use them to manage the log file size, or just get a bigger disk for the log file.